# What is wrong with this answer

Tags: function, scheme, lisp, racket

```
(define inc (lambda(x)((+ x 1 ))))
```

I created the line of code above as an answer to the question

> "Create a function called "inc" which will be given a numeric argument, and returns a number larger by one.
> For instance,
> `(inc 6) => 7`"

Comment: How do you know it is wrong? do you get an error message? in which case, what is it?

Answer (score 3):

You have an extra set of parentheses. You want

```
(define inc (lambda(x)(+ x 1 )))
```

instead of

```
(define inc (lambda(x)((+ x 1 ))))
```